# Finding restrictions and convex hull by having a set of extreme points

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, convex-hulls

Suppose we are given a set of extreme points. Is it possible to find out all possible restrictions of the Linear Programming problem by having those extreme points? Well, if we have a linear programming problem we might be able to find out the extreme points via certain algorithm. What I am asking is whether it is possible to reverse the process and somehow find the restrictions and convex hull from the given set of extreme points? Do you know any resources for investigating such problems?

Comment: I'm not sure if this answers your question, but the Krein Milman Theorem tells us that a closed convex set is the closed convex hull of its extreme points in finite dimensions.

Comment: @TheoBendit This helps! Anyways, my question is not particularly about the existence of solution. Although I didn't know much about the existence criteria, I was told to investigate a practical algorithm or set of steps to find out restrictions and convex hull. By pinpointing this theorem I think I got more confidence on the validity of my question and journey to find out a solution.

Comment: Yes it’s possible but quite hard. I use [QHull](http://www.qhull.org/) to do this (although it really breaks down after for dimensions larger than say $n=10$).

Comment: @DavidM. I have checked out the algorithm you mentioned. However, this algorithm does not specify the restrictions? How is one supposed to find the restrictions of the polygon? In addition, QHull algorithm does not get Extreme points as an input but a set of points.

Comment: By restrictions I assume you mean linear inequalities, right? If so, QHull can in fact do that. Do I misunderstand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may misunderstand what you mean by "restrictions" so please correct me if I'm wrong. I'm assuming you mean "linear inequalities that define the convex hull". If so, Qhull can take a set of extreme points and spit out the linear description.

Here's a simple example: suppose you want to compute the linear description of the convex hull of the points $(0,0,0$), $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$. First, you need a file containing those three points in the right format:

```
3
4
0 0 0
1 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 1
```

The first line indicates the dimension that the points live in (3). The second line indicates how many points there are (4). Each subsequent line contains a point.

Call this file `points.dat`. Then to compute the linear description of the convex hull with QHull, call

`/path/to/qhull n < points.dat`

The `n` flag tells QHull to compute the linear description (or "normals with offsets" as it's referred to in the [QHull documentation](http://qhull.org/html/qhull.htm)). The output looks like this:

```
4
4
    -0     -0     -1      0 
     0     -1      0     -0 
    -1     -0     -0      0 
0.5773502691896258 0.5773502691896258 0.5773502691896258 -0.5773502691896258
```

The first line contains the dimension plus one, the second line contains the number of linear inequalities (facets). Each subsequent row is an inequality. In this case, the first 3 values are the coefficients of the three variables, and the last value is the NEGATIVE of the right-hand-side. The inequalities are in $\leq$ form. So for example, the final inequality above is
$$
0.577{x_1}+0.577{x_2}+0.577{x_3}\leq0.577
$$
or, dividing away $0.577$:
$$
x_1+x_2+x_3\leq1.
$$

**Caveats**

1. This only works in pretty low dimension. The QHull website says that they do not support computation in dimension $n\geq9$. I have found that for structured polyhedra, I can sometimes get up to $n=12$, but not higher.
2. This method requires that the convex hull of the input points is full-dimensional (*i.e.* $n$-dimensional). If it's not, QHull will fail.
3. This will also work if you call `qconvex` instead of `qhull`. I don't think the choice makes a difference (pretty sure it's the same code under the hood).
4. I don't claim this is the best way to do this--just that it will work.

Comment: @DavidM.Exactly what I wanted. However, is there any theoretical explanation of what's going on under the hood to find out the facets(Linear inequalities)? Well, what I had found about QHull didn't explain how one should proceed to find out the facets it seems some special things are going on under the hood?

Comment: The QHull website provides a reference for their paper (entitled "The Quickhull algorithm for convex hulls"), which explains the algorithm. There's also a simplified explanation [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/quickhull-algorithm-convex-hull/). Unfortunately I don't know much about computational geometry, so I won't be much help there.

Comment: You've already done a great job of explaining what's going on! I dig further if I found anything useful I would post it as a complementary answer.